# How to show alertview indicator before pulling json data( iOS6 )

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Could any one please help me with this code i'm trying to call alertview indicator before pulling json data in my iOS app but i don't know how to check if the data already loaded and then disappear the alertview indicator, For now it always appears even all data aleady loaded. here is my code:

```
//
//  Firstcine.m
//  
//
//  
//

#import "Firstcine.h"

@interface Firstcine (){

UIAlertView *loading;

}

@end

@implementation Firstcine

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


// Loading Show Alert View...
loading = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Please Wait..." 
delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
UIActivityIndicatorView *progress= [[UIActivityIndicatorView 
alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125, 50, 30, 30)];
progress.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
[loading addSubview:progress];
[progress startAnimating];
[loading show];


// dis play all  data after first  loaded


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/App/first.php"];

NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:
jsonData  options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];



// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_tile.png"]];




NSDictionary *dict = [json objectAtIndex:0];
name.text = [dict valueForKey:@"name"];
time.text = [dict valueForKey:@"time"];
date.text = [dict valueForKey:@"date"];
price.text = [dict valueForKey:@"price"];

// then display photo

UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 87, 150,200)];
image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
[NSURL URLWithString:[dict  valueForKey:@"photo" ]]]];

[self.view addSubview:image];










}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Configuring Preferences\nPlease Wait..."
                          message:nil
                          delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:nil
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alertView show];

UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
indicator.center = CGPointMake(alertView.bounds.size.width / 2, alertView.bounds.size.height - 50);
[indicator startAnimating];
[alertView addSubview:indicator];


dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("saver", NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{

    // do some heavy lifting ? like a fetch

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // hide the view
        [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    });
});
```

Comment: thought you had that working, edit about with alert view code for you

Comment: Thanks a lot for help it works quite well, but i just wondering the indicator activity still spinning even the alert box is disappeared and the data is all pulled, so any suggestion about stop the indicator animation after certain event is finised

Comment: [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES] should remove the alert and the spinner (as it is a subview). Depending where you call this method is when it will be removed.